# Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted when importing orders

Tags: orders, importexport

we are using this extension : https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/bulk-import-export-orders-to-csv.html

when we try to import one order , its working fine.

when we trying to import the more orders, we are getting this error :

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 66 bytes) in /var/www/html/sitename/lib/Zend/Log/Formatter/Simple.php on line 103
```

but exporting is fine.

please help me to find solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Magento comes with a default .htaccess file in the root directory that includes this configuration directive:

```
php_value memory_limit sizeinMBs
```

Comment this line by placing # at starting or try increasing this size to 512MB or more (depending on your need). Also If you can, try changing `memory_limit` in PHP.ini file.

Comment: in .htaccess we have 1024 M now... php_value memory_limit : 1024M

Comment: You have Hard Coded 32M memory_limit.

If you are running a shared server, your memory_limit in PHP.ini may be locked down to 32M so you're forced to fairly share resources with others on the server. Magento doesn't run well on shared servers that have not been optimized for Magento.

Your server may not be set up to use memory_limit out of .htaccess and thus requires you to use a PHP.ini file to set memory.

Check with your hosting service provider and ask them to bump the memory_limit to 512M in PHP.ini file.

Comment: we are not using shared hosting. i checked with our server team, they increased in php.ini file to 512M. but still same error

Comment: Try this to put on index.php: ini_set('memory_limit', '512M');